# Entropy and neutral charge

Tags: statistical-mechanics, charge, entropy, information

If you have a system $a$ with $N$ particles with charge $+q$ and you put it in contact with a system $b$ that has $N$ particles with charge $-q$, i think the system will evolve to a neutral charged system. So my question is this, if the natural way on which the particles arrange themselves is the way of maximezating the entropy, is the charge neutrality a state of maxium disorder, or in other words minimum information?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague but here is how to think about it. A spontaneous process always *increases* entropy. Hold the positive and negative charges at some position, then let them free. If they come to a new equilibrium position, then the final state has higher entropy.